# For collinear points $A-C-P-D-B$ it is true that $p$ is the midpoint of segments $AB$ and $CD$. If $d(A,B)=3d(C,D)$ and $d(A,C)=2$ then $d(C,D)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I can't solve this exercise, I try to apply midpoint properties but I don't get the answer.
Some clue?

For collinear points $A-C-P-D-B$ it is true that $p$ is the midpoint of segments $AB$ and $CD$. If $d(A,B)=3d(C,D)$ and $d(A,C)=2$. Calcule $d(C,B)$.

---

I try
How $d(A,B)=d(A,C)+d(C,D)+d(D,B)$, then
$$3d(C,D)=d(A,C)+d(C,D)+d(D,B)$$
But $d(A,C)=2$.
I'm not sure about this, but I can affirm that $d(D,B)=2$?.

Comment: What is the value of that measure. Maybe Calcule $d(C,D)$

Comment: Can you show that $d(A,C) = d(D, B)$? Hint: P is the midpoint of AB and CD, so $PA = PB, PC = PD$.

Comment: Yes, that's my question, I wasn't quite sure. My answer is $4$.

Comment: Did you read my hint?

Comment: mm yes then I think I didn't understand the hint.